# Sed (OS X) replace block of text containing given string with other block of text

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I'd like to replace all lines containing Test.bundle (those lines are grouped in one block) with other files

from

```
<ItemGroup>
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\some_other_file.json" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\one.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\two.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\three.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to

```
<ItemGroup>
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\some_other_file.json" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\four.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\five.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\six.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\seven.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What I did

```
res=$(find Resources/Test.bundle -type f | sed 's/\\/\//g' | xargs -I {} echo "<BundleResource Include=\"{}\" />") #get new files, change path delimiters, wrap file names in output pattern
sed -E -i '' '/Test\.bundle/,/ItemGroup/c\
BUNDLE_PLACEHOLDER' file.ext #remove whole block from first line containing Test.bundle to closing ItemGroup and replace with placeholder
sed -E -i '' "s:BUNDLE_PLACEHOLDER:$res:" file.ext #replace with new block
```

I couldn't change it in one pass in the third command due to `"extra characters after \ at the end of c command"` so I changed it to the string placeholder that I was trying to replace in the next command. That also failed due to `unescaped newline inside substitute pattern` that I'm currently trying to solve. There is also missing closing ItemGroup tag that will be added later.

Are there any other options using sed?

Can I catch only group containing Test.bundle without catching closing ItemGroup?

How to escape newlines to satisfy the substitution pattern?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're really trying to match on but this might be what you want:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    new = new $0 ORS
    next
}
/Test\.bundle/ {
    printf "%s", new
    new = ""
    next
}
{ print }
' new old
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat old
<ItemGroup>
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\some_other_file.json" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\one.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\two.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\three.png" />
</ItemGroup>

$ cat new
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\four.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\five.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\six.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\seven.png" />
```

.

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    new = new $0 ORS
    next
}
/Test\.bundle/ {
    printf "%s", new
    new = ""
    next
}
{ print }
' new old
<ItemGroup>
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\some_other_file.json" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\four.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\five.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\six.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\seven.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `sed` isn't really your best option here, but since you *asked* for `sed`...
Here's a crude first pass.

```
$: cat new
<ItemGroup>
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\some_other_file.json" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\four.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\five.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\six.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\seven.png" />
</ItemGroup>

$: cat old
stuff before

...

more stuff

<ItemGroup>
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\some_other_file.json" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\one.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\two.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\three.png" />
</ItemGroup>

stuff after

...

more stuff.

$: sed -n '/<ItemGroup>/,/<[/]ItemGroup>/{ /<ItemGroup>/h;
     /<[/]ItemGroup>/{ H; s/^.*//; x; /Test[.]bundle/{ s/^.*/cat new/e; }; p; d; }
     H; d; }; p; ' old
stuff before

...

more stuff

<ItemGroup>
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\some_other_file.json" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\four.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\five.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\six.png" />
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Test.bundle\seven.png" />
</ItemGroup>

stuff after

...

more stuff.
```

This obviously makes some simple assumptions about your file structure.

The same logic in `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { new=new$0"\n"; next; }
  /<ItemGroup>/,/<[/]ItemGroup>/{ grp=grp$0"\n";
    if ($0 ~ "</ItemGroup>") { if (grp ~ "Test.bundle") { print new } else { print grp } grp="" } else next;
  } 1' new old
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Unfortunately, OS X sed seems to be incompatible with e param and throws

bad flag in substitute command: 'e'

Comment: Did you try the `awk`?